# Service and Notification refreshed when Activity is closed

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a Service with a Notification with a Progress Bar inside. This Service is started when i open the Main Activity and works fine. But, when i close Main Activity (onDestroy() is called) the Notification is like refreshed. This is the code of my Service.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();               

        Mypreferences prefs = new Mypreferences(this);

        String minutes = prefs.getStringValueOf("Minutes");

        final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        d = Integer.valueOf(minutes)*60;

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_about);
        builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i=0;i<d;i++) {
                    builder.setProgress(d, d-i, false);
                    builder.setContentInfo(d-i+"/"+d);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }               
        }).start();
```

Integer d it's 60 and countdown works fine but when i close MainActivity if for example ProgressBar is at 40, return to 60. Why? How can i solve?

Service code

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    pref = new SharedPref(this);
    map = pref.getAllPrefs();

    boolean delay = pref.loadBooleanPref("delay");
    String delayTime = pref.loadStringValue("DelayTime");

    if(delay && delayTime != null) {
        new CountDownTimer(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Long.valueOf(delayTime)), 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getInfo();
            }

        }.start();
    } else {
        getInfo();
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont see any code that set your prefs MINUTE.

Comment: you should post your `MainActivity` code. Your code should work fine if you do nothing in your `MainActivity`. Maybe you do something that start this service again when close activity.

Comment: In Main Activity i only start the service

Comment: I guess something else updates the value of "d" but we need to see the whole code to be sure. Also you should stop your thread when your Activity is destroyed. If you want the progress bar to be updated when your app is in the background, use a Service instead.

Comment: the code  above works fine. You should post your `MainActivity` and your `Service` code (all classes, not only the block of code that you think it's wrong)

Comment: updated. i posted the service class. In Main activity i start only the service and nothing other.